# Accurev's "show" Command : "-t" flag does not work

Tags: accurev

On the command line in Windows, I'm tring to run:

```
accurev show -p <myDepotName> -t 2011/11/09 13:26:19 streams
```

After I enter this command, the accurev help just prints out for accurev show.

Please advise me on how to use the accurev show command.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose the -t argument in quotes -

```
accurev show -p <myDepotName> -t "2011/11/09 13:26:19" streams
```